# jqueryui tabs: identifying a new tab to add content to it

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using the jqueryui tabs code, adding new tabs, and dynamically creating new content in the new tabs via ajax. However, the problem is that I can't reliably select the new tab, and my new content goes in the first tab.
The code I'm using is as follows:

```
var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({
   tabTemplate: "...etc",
   add: function(event, ui) {

   $(ui.panel).append("<p id=\"demo\"></p>");

   $.ajax({
     type:     "POST",
     url:      "comms.php",
     data:     {country:tab_content},
     dataType: "script"
});
```

php code on the server writes to the 'demo' para, but the problem is that `$(ui.panel)` always selects 'demo' in the first tab. I've tried some variations on this, including

```
$('tabs').tabs("select", ui.panel.id);
$(ui.panel).append("<p id=\"demo\"></p>");
```

and

```
var top  = $(ui.panel).get(0);
var demo = document.createElement("p");
demo.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "demo");
top.appendChild(demo);
```

with no luck. Any idea how I select the new tab for output? Thanks.

Comment: The ID of your `<p>` must be unique, now you all call them "demo" in each tab, which is not valid. Try making the IDs unique or select via a class selector for instance.

Comment: Thanks Didier - yes, it was a dumb question. Fixed by uniquifying the IDs, as you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your problem happens because all the `<div>` you append to `ui.panel` in your `add` callback have the same ID. It **must** be unique.

Try giving them a different ID.